# Opening the Excel application from Python

Tags: python, excel, browser

I am using 'xlwt' to write into Excel files as part of my project in Python. I also need to actually open the Excel spreadsheet for display and also close it. I found a function:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('C:/Users/300231823/Desktop/GUI/simplenew4.xls')
```

This seems to open the .xls file. How do I close the file?

I am completely new to programming, and I started using Python 3 weeks ago.

Answer (score 15):

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True # otherwise excel is hidden

# newest excel does not accept forward slash in path
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\Users\300231823\Desktop\GUI\simplenew4.xls')
wb.Close()
xl.Quit()
```

The win32com module is part of [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).

Comment: Is there way to find out if simplenew4.xls is closed, and if not, close it?

Comment: `for book in xl.Workbooks: if book.Name=='simplenew4.xls': book.Close()`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can also use [XLWings](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/connect_to_workbook.html#python-to-excel):

```
>>> app = xw.App()  # or something like xw.apps[0] for existing apps
>>> app.books['Book1']
```