# repairing Excel file

Tags: python, macos, import-from-excel

I have about 1500 excel spreadsheet files downloaded from movescount.com - these contain heart rate data taken over a few years. I want to process these files with a bit of Python + openpyxl.  The problem is that opening the excel file with openpyxl fails. Specifically it complains that a styles.xml definition is missing. Also Apple’s Numbers cannot open the file. When I open the file with MS Excel (which works) and simply save the file right away, I can open and process it with python and openpyxl just fine.

Clearly, MS Excel is repairing some format issue. But I would like to avoid having to open and save the file with MS Excel - particularly because that means I need to do this on an MS Windows box. What is the best way to repair these files on the fly on my OS X machine?

Comment: If you can get an hour on a windows box you may want to try [automating excel via COM](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28488725/1322401) to just open, save, and close the workbooks.  (At about 2 seconds per workbook it should take 50 minutes.)

Comment: Have you tried [pyXLSX](https://github.com/leegao/pyXLSX) or [python-xlsx](https://github.com/staale/py-xlsx)?  I believe that openpyxl is the best python Excel library, but trying the alternatives may give you something that doesn't barf on these particular files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Excel xlsx file is a zipped archive of files.  So you can write the missing file to the xlsx archive provided you have one good file to start with.

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('/path/to/goodfile.xlsx', 'r') as zgood:
    styles_xml = zgood.read('xl/styles.xml')

with zipfile.ZipFile('/path/to/badfile.xlsx', 'a') as zbad:
    zbad.writestr('xl/styles.xml', styles_xml)
```