# How to properly add a table to a write-only openpyxl sheet?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to load an excel sheet with data, put a table over it, and then save it again. Unfortunately I needed a roundabout way to do this because the excel file is too large to open and save normally with openpyxl (~120,000 rows; gives MemoryError when saving) so I need to open it as a read-only workbook, then write it to a new write-only workbook. This is what I have so far (headers is a string array with length that matches the # of columns in the file):

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table, TableStyleInfo
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

# Load excel file
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excelFile, read_only=True)
ws = wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]

# Create table
maxRow = ws.max_row
maxCol = get_column_letter(ws.max_column)
tab = Table(displayName="Table1", ref=f"A1:{maxCol}{maxRow}")
style = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium9", showFirstColumn=False,
                       showLastColumn=False, showRowStripes=True, showColumnStripes=True)

tab.tableStyleInfo = style

# Create a new workbook and add a worksheet with optimized write
newBook = openpyxl.Workbook(write_only=True)
newSheet = newBook.create_sheet()
newSheet.title = 'test'

for row in ws.rows:
    newSheet.append((cell.value for cell in row))

# Initialize headers and add to table
tab._initialise_columns()
for column, value in zip(tab.tableColumns, headers):
    column.name = value

# Add table
newSheet.add_table(tab)  # Warning here
newBook.save(f"C:\\testSaveDirec\\test.xlsx")
```

I've read the documentation on adding tables in write-only mode and believe I'm doing it correctly, but when I try to add the table to the sheet with `newSheet.add_table(tab)` It gives me the warning:

`warn("In write-only mode you must add table columns manually")`

When I open the file once it has saved, the file is corrupt and excel says it found a problem with the file.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Since you're on Windows, you would have better results by using COM to control the `Excel.Application` directly.  Excel, like all the Office applications, has a vast API.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282230/opening-the-excel-application-from-python

Comment: @TimRoberts just tried this out and it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: I **think** you have to do the headers (data missing in code) after adding the table to the worksheet. Things will be a little faster if you use values_only but doing this kind of thing directly in Excel is probably best. It would, in theory, be possible to edit the XLSX directly but this wouldn't be for the faint-hearted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update- Fixed by using the win32com module. New code:

```py
import win32com.client

exc = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
exc.Visible = 0
exc.Workbooks.Open(Filename=excelFile)

# Add headers
for idx, hd in enumerate(headers):
    exc.Cells(1, idx + 1).Value = hd

exc.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select()
exc.Selection.Columns.AutoFit()
exc.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add().TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9"
exc.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
```

** This code replaces the first row with headers, because my first row was blank but I'm sure there are ways to insert a new first row w/ headers

Comment: Btw, `exc.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select()`, `exc.Selection.Columns.AutoFit()` can be simplified to `exc.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit()`.

Comment: You might also want to give xlwings a look.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution in openpyxl

### Correct procedure

1. Write table headers into Worksheet (Worksheet.append)
2. Write table data into Worksheet (Worksheet.append)
3. Calculate table range
4. Create an instance of the Table class
5. Manually initialize table columns (dirty hack — table._initialise_columns)
6. Manually name table columns (example in openpyxl documentation)
7. Attach a table to Worksheet (Worksheet.add_table)

### add_table() function example

```
from collections.abc import Collection, Iterable

from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table, TableStyleInfo
from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet


def coord2range(left: tuple[int, int], right: tuple[int, int]) -> str:
    return f"{get_column_letter(left[0])}{left[1]}:{get_column_letter(right[0])}{right[1]}"


def add_table(ws: Worksheet, name_table: str, headers: Collection, current_row: int = 1, data: Iterable[Iterable] = [],
              style: TableStyleInfo = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium5", showFirstColumn=False,
                                                     showLastColumn=False, showRowStripes=True,
                                                     showColumnStripes=False)) -> Table:
    first_row = current_row
    last_row = current_row

    ws.append(headers)
    for row in data:
        ws.append(row)
        last_row = last_row + 1

    last_row = last_row if (last_row > first_row) else first_row + 1
    range = coord2range((1, first_row), (len(headers), last_row))

    table = Table(displayName=name_table, tableStyleInfo=style, ref=range)

    table._initialise_columns()
    for col, value in zip(table.tableColumns, headers):
        col.name = value if value else col.name

    ws.add_table(table)
    return table
```

### Usage example

```
import contextlib
from openpyxl import Workbook

headers = ("стлб 1", "стлб 2", "стлб 3")
data = [
    ["данные 1", "данные 2", " данные 3"],
    ["данные 4", "данные 5", " данные 6"],
    ["данные 7", "данные 8", " данные 9"],
]

with contextlib.closing(Workbook(write_only=True)) as wb:
    ws = wb.create_sheet("лист1")
    t = add_table(ws, "Таблица", headers, data=data)
    wb.save(r"path\test1.xlsx")
```

### Note

1. Warning *«warn("In write-only mode you must add table columns manually")»* does not affect operation.
2. “current_row” is the number of the row into which the table will be inserted. The first row in the worksheet uses the default value (1).
   I don’t know how to automatically determine the current location of adding a line.

p.s. It seems that the openpyxl library needs to expand its support for working with Table. Table is a very convenient thing.